# Android: Is it possible to Swipe between two Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe-gesture

I want to swipe between two activities (NOT FRAGMENT ) both activities are extended from ActionBarACtivity , so it is possible or not ? If possible then how it will done?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But the use case you are describing is very fit for use of fragments. Can I ask why you don't want to use fragments?

Comment: why you wanna `activities` instead of `fragments` ?

Comment: `activity` is a big memory hunting object so two activites in the same screen can lead to huge memory usage and could leak on of them.. so try fragment

Comment: And if not possible? Because your answer is no

Comment: Fragments are notoriously difficult to deal with in the lifecycle, especially during debugging.

Comment: @Mohamed Fadel Buffon 
Actually in one activity I have map and lot of work done in this mapActivity which cant be implement in fragment

Comment: you could make two activities with transition when swipe fake `view pager` it's guarantee

Comment: @nbokmans how it is possible ? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MohamedFadelBuffon Okayyy I will check

Comment: @android you can use maps in fragment instead with activity

Comment: @MohamedFadelBuffon But How I implement LocationLIstener methods in map fragment ?

Comment: @android make map fragment implements locationlistener it's easy like what you do in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending an activity does not meant that they are related in the screen or window, `activity` class is an abstraction or a class where you can put your logic into. Since Every activity is attached to a single window, sure it is possible.
Look at libraries like [this](https://github.com/liuguangqiang/SwipeBack), it will provide you easy helper function to implement this, or read the code to customise it ;)

Since this involves lots of code, you can also look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA) or [sliding activity](https://github.com/klinker41/android-slidingactivity) for getting an idea of implementing it ;)

NOTE: only way to do is start second activity & then control its visibility

Answer (score 0):

You can swipe between two activities, try this code.

**In Kotlin:**

```
class Main3Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

internal var x1: Float = 0.toFloat()
internal var x2: Float = 0.toFloat()
internal var y1: Float = 0.toFloat()
internal var y2: Float = 0.toFloat()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
}

override fun onTouchEvent(tochevent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (tochevent.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            x1 = tochevent.x
            y1 = tochevent.y
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            x2 = tochevent.x
            y2 = tochevent.y
            if (x1 < x2) {
                val i = Intent(this@Main3Activity, Main2Activity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Does this allow swiping down to dismiss the current activity.

Comment: I don't think so but you can try it and see if it works for you